# Correction In Code For cURL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

I wanted make "a service on one site" to be available on my site.
so I decided to use cURL(Before I have tried using Iframe but it is not worthy as that site has ads, I want Specific Part Etc.) so basically i want specific tag(not div) from that remote site On my website's webpage. I googled a lot as I don't know php and found that cURL is used to do what I wanted. After googling more I have Made This Simple Script

```
    <?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.autogeneratelink.com/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
echo "$output";
?>
```

As I don't know php I could only make this much so basically what this code do is display whole site on my webpage but I want specific part (Things Between This Tag `<form method="POST" action=""></form>`)

Also I have tried to enter a value in my webpage and clicking "Generate" button but it do not do Anything. It just refreshes the page.

Pls.. Help me regarding this I want Button to work properly and the Content Between That tag Only.

Thank You Guys For Helping..

Comment: Is There A Special Reason For Capitalizing Every Word To Make Your Question Unreadable?

Comment: Please use proper grammar.

Comment: @gadhvi, after retrieving the markup, look into using PHP's `DOM` processor to extract what you need.

Comment: @Rasclatt As I Said I Don't Know php Can U Help Me With That And What Abt The Button TO Work??

Answer (score 0):

You can run `preg_match` on the results of curl to obtain the HTML you want:

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.autogeneratelink.com/");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $html = curl_exec ($curl);
  curl_close ($curl);
  preg_match('/<form method="POST" action="">.*<\/form>/s', $html, $matches);
  $form = $matches[0];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="http://www.autogeneratelink.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://www.autogeneratelink.com/css/autogl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    button#submit{
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Awesome Page</h1>
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <?php echo $form ?>
  <p>Bye!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the form is powered by [the following script](http://www.autogeneratelink.com/js/yudamo-gl.js), which makes an Ajax request to a PHP script on a domain outside of your control. You will be clobbered by the cross-origin policy and your form won't work. There is no way that I know of to get around this. Sorry!

Plus, at this point, you should also start thinking about the ethics of what you are doing (i.e. stealing).

Comment: Sir I have Asked Admin To Do WHat I want and also I have also found one site which is doing actually what I want. So I think the submit button will work there should be something.... PLs. Help me regarding the Generate Button

Comment: THe Url to another Site : (torrent.digitalmaza.net/directlink/)

Comment: You can do the same thing with that site, but as you can see by looking at the source code, there is no action defined for the form: `<form name="f1" action="" method="post">` This means you'll have to find the JavaScript powering the form and include that too (hoping it doesn't make any Ajax requests).

Comment: Sir I am Saying That The Secont Url(Digitalmaza) is using curl To Get Data from autogeneratelinks I meant That Digitalmaza is doing what i have asked for... scrap autogenerate links using curl

Comment: So Can u Tell Me How I can Change Looks Of Curled Content?? As Digitmalmaza has Done?? I meant i want it to Look As I wish??

Comment: Depends what you mean by "change looks". Maybe use CSS?

Comment: I meant That Can I Change COlor Of Button Etc. If Yes How??

Comment: As I said, use CSS. I've updated my answer with a simple example.

Comment: Where Is Examle ??? I can't Find Sir... yet thnx for Help And try If U could Help Me using button Sir. Thank You For Your reply... :) :)

Comment: Refresh the page and look at my answer. Example is within <style> tags in the <head> section of the code.

Comment: Can't You tell me how admin of digitalmaza has done that?? working Submit button etc.

Comment: I asked Digitalmaza's Admin He Told me that It is simple I just have to make a form in html and in that I have to call the page in which i am using to curl AGL . then on the time of display i will have to echo curl So can anyone help me regarding this??